# How to avoid CSS selector applying to more than one level of descendants

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent CSS from applying my styles do descendants of descendants without giving them classes or ids? e.g.

```
#mycontent table {border: 1px solid red;}
```

Will style the correct table, and then ALL tables inside that one too. All I want is the first table to be selected, not all the subtables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you describe is not the cascade, it is simple selector matching.

There are a few approaches that you could take.

The first is to use a selector that is more specific. If the table you want to style is a child (rather than a grandchilder or other deeper descendent) then you can use a child selector instead of a descendent selector. This is **not** supported in MSIE 6.

```
#mycontent > table { border: 1px solid red; }
```

The second is to add more information to the tables you actually want to style (with an id or class).

```
#mycontent table.tableThatIWantToStyle {}
```

The third is to make use of the cascade and style the deeper descendants differently.

```
#mycontent table { border: 1px solid red; }
#mycontent table table { border: none; }
```

That said, if you have tables inside tables then the odds are that you are abusing them for layout - which is wrong - and you should fix your markup instead.

Comment: I disagree that tables for column layouts are wrong, since with CSS you have to hack it anyhow... so it's just a matter of choosing one's poison.

Comment: I'll choose the one where I use a presentation tool for presentation and don't claim data relationships that do not exist.

Comment: I accept your solution, I was hoping that there was a better way to make cross browser selections, since sometimes one cannot control the HTML sufficiently and needs to control elements indirectly by their position in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the child selector:

```
#mycontent > table {border: 1px solid red;}
```

The problem is the child selector isn't supported in IE6. If you need to support that browser you'll have to do something a lot more clunky:

```
#mycontent table {border: 1px solid red;}
#mycontent table table {border: none;}
```

Alternatively you can discriminate the tables using classes so you don't get this cascade effect.

Comment: If #document refers to a table, this will not work. If it is a div, then it will.

Answer (score 0):

Give your table a type (class):

```
table.mycontent {border: 1px solid red;}
```

All child tables should not be marked with .mycontent. Then the style will only be applied to the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just give that one HTML table tag an id, 'mycontent', and write the CSS as follows:

```
table#mycontent {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar dilemma and here is how I worked around it.  My solution is similar to what others have posted with regard to using more specific selectors to match appropriately.

Suppose I have a nested span as follows and I don't want styles to cascade to it.

```
<span class="boldText">
     some bolded text
     <span class="italicText">some italic text</span>
</span>
```

In other words, I want it to appear as "**some bolded text** *some italic text*" rather than "**some bolded text *some italic text***" (and vice versa).  By setting a specific selector to clear these styles on nested children this can be achieved as follows.

```
span span {
   font-weight:normal; /*clear bold style from 'cascading' by specifying it*/
   font-style:normal; /*clear italic style from 'cascading' by specifying it*/
}
.boldText {
   font-weight:bold;
}
.italicText {
   font-style:italic;
}
```

The "span span" selector can ensure that the nested span will have its styles set to anything necessary to override normally cascaded style from the parent span, setting them back to a "normal" un-styled state.  Then the specific boldText or italicText classes on the spans themselves will apply next giving the content of that span either bold or italics (or both) since they are more specific selectors.

The convenience here is that I no longer have to worry about the font formatting style on a parent cascading to a child.  I can simply add the appropriate formatting class to any span and have only that class apply, without that of the parent.

I could just as easily have added a ".clearBold" and ".clearItalic" class to all nested spans, but this is cleaner and resulted in less code in my application.

Comment: The question explicitly indicates that additional classes are not desired and this answer is far less relevant than existing answers.